# vector pointers, inheritance

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, vector

**Hi.I have 2 questions.

1) I'm doing a copy constructor's. 
The statement I made is:**

```
ticket_office& operator=(const ticket_office& d);
```

**but, When I perform the function that now I post you:**

```
ticket_office&::operator= (const ticket_office& d){

sizeTickets_sold=d.sizeTickets_sold;
capacityTickets_sold=d.capacityTickets_sold;

if(this!=&d){

    Tickets_for_sale=d.Tickets_for_sale;

    Tickets_sold=new Ticket[d.capacity];

    for(int i=0;i<sizeTickets_sold;i++){
        Tickets_sold[i]=d.Tickets_sold[i];
    }
}

return* this;
}
```

The compilator gives me this error:-

> 1) [Error] explicit qualification in declaration of 'Ticket_office& operator=(const Ticket_office&)'"
>
> 2) [Error] 'Ticket_office& operator=(const Ticket_office&)' must be a nonstatic member function"

Why? I don't understand?

And the second question:

2)If I create a class that inherits in public from another, the daughter class can access all elements of the mother class that are public and protected but not privately, right?

And if inherited in protected?
And in private?

I understand that in all 3 cases, the child class can access public and protected items, but can not access private items. But what is the real difference?

Answer (score 3):

1. Your operator definition needs both a qualifier and a return type.  Try `Ticket_office& Ticket_office::operator =(const Ticket_office &d)`.

   By the way, this is not a copy constructor. This is a copy-assignment operator. A copy constructor would actually look like a constructor, and take a `const Ticket_office&` as its parameter. Like `Ticket_office::Ticket_office(const Ticket_office &other)`.
2. If you say `class A : public B`, then yes, *member functions of `A`* can access public and protected members of `B`. Outsiders can only access the public stuff, and `A` can't access the privates of `B`.

   The difference between public, private, and protected inheritance is in what classes *other* than `A` can see when they're talking to an instance of `A`<sup>*</sup>.

   - With public inheritance, everyone can see the stuff that was public in `B`, and subclasses of `A` have access to the protected stuff.
   - With protected inheritance, only subclasses of `A` have access to the public and protected members of `B`.
   - With private inheritance, only `A` itself can access `B`'s members.

<sup><sup>*</sup>I forget exactly how private and protected inheritance work with regard to base-class pointers. Common sense would suggest that you can see the public stuff if you're talking to an `A` through a pointer/reference to `B`, but lose access once you downcast.</sup>